# Go App Engine nested objects are not stored in Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I have a entity EmergencyCase that has 2 embedded structs (1 array and 1 struct)
When I try to save the EmergencyCase by calling:

```
datastore.Put(c, key, &ec)
```

Everything is stored fine except the Pos field (type Position). There is no error or log entry about this. It is just not stored. Any suggestions?

Here are my 3 entities definitions:

```
type Position struct{
    lon float32
    lat float32
}
type EmergencyCase struct{
    // Autogenerated id, not stored in the database.
    ID string `datastore:"-"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    Closed bool
    ClosedByUser bool `datastore:",noindex"`
    AutoClosed bool `datastore:",noindex"`
    Pos Position
    Events []Event
}

type Event struct{
    // Autogenerated id, not stored in the datastore.
    ID string `datastore:"-"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    Name string `datastore:",noindex"`
}
```

Comment: you won't have a Pos field in the datastore, but you will have lon / lat fields .. is that the case ?

Comment: No that was not the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Export](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) the Position field names by uppercasing the first letter in the name.  The datastore [stores exported fields only](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/entities#Go_Creating_an_entity).

```
type Position struct{
  Lon float32
  Lat float32
}
```

Comment: That was the mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try using [appengine.GeoPoint](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/reference#GeoPoint) as an altenative/optimised class